# fadeIn() function - what change if a div is hide or not?

Tags: jquery

I see on internet that many times the function `fadeIn()` is preceded by the function `hide()`, but in fact I can't understand what's the difference between put it before or not : the result is the same!

Who know? :)

Comment: Agree. I usually set display: none in the div's style and I don't need to use hide() so far.

Comment: Ok! But the result of a div hidden or not, using fadeIn(), is the same...

Comment: I mean : if a div have got display: none or not, the result is the same :O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hide() is there incase it's already on show I guess, and to make sure it's hidden before they fade it in.

Comment: Yes but why? The behaviour is the same if a div is hide or not :)